# How to access configuration parameters from any class in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, model, config

I've got a simple Model class that loads and saves a file:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Model;

class WidgetModel {

    public function load() {}

    public function save() {}

}
```

From this class, I need to access configuration parameters defined in `config.yml`:

```
parameters:
    widgets:
        1:
            width: 300
            height: 250
        2:
            width: 240
            height: 320
```

In a controller, I would normally use the syntax `$widgetConfig = $this->getParameter('widget');` but obviously it won't work in this case.

What would be the correct way to do this from any class?

Comment: It looks like you need to create a service for this to work with parameters.  Checkout @Diego's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are speaking about a Service, you can [inject parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html).

If you speak about inject parameters in your Entities, it is sadly bad practise. A Symfony Entity is designed to be POPO (plain old php object), so it should not know anything outside its scope (that is, no persistence, no container, ...).